# Laravel Eloquent non-lambda parameters

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve a number of results from database using eloquent.
I dont have problem with that. 
Example code

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
               ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

Now lets suppose I have a variable that if it's true i want to add one more WHERE clause. For example if $domestic == true then i want something like this:

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
               ->where('domestic',1)
               ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

So I dont like to do, because it's not nice.

```
if($domestic) { 
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
                   ->where('domestic',1)
                   ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                   ->take(10)
                   ->get();
} else {
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
                   ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                   ->take(10)
                   ->get();
}
```

Ideally i want to pass only the where clause eg.

```
if(@domestic) { $flights->where('domestic',1) }
```

But this is not working.

What is the best way to pass additional where clauses whenever needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
    ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
    ->when($domestic, function ($query){
        return $query->where('domestic',1)
    })
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

The laravel query builder has some real gems like the `when` clause, the when clause will only execute the closure if the first parameter is true (in this case `$domestic`)

This specific function can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#conditional-clauses). On the same way more of these functions can be found.

Comment: Even all answers are correct - I think i'll prefer this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1);
if($domestic) { 
    $flights->where('domestic',1);
}
$results = $flights->orderBy('name', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes)

Write them on your model, quick example on flight model:

```
public function scopeIsDomestic($query,$domestic){
    if($domestic == 1){
      return $query->where('domestic',1);
   }else{
      return $query; //you can return the inverse if you need it -> where domestic <> 1
   }
}
```

And now use it like this

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
           ->isDomestic(1)
           ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
           ->take(10)
           ->get();
```

It provides a nice way to keep the code maintainable since you can update the scope on all your queries at the same time by modifying it on a single place

Comment: Scopes are indeed a perfect use case for this *if* the query if reused I think it might be overkill if the query is only used once.

Comment: Yeah, it will be overextend if you are going to use it once. I didn't know `->when()` , great to know about